# Is there a general method to count ordered pairs of integers $(a,b)$ such that $ab<x$ for some given $x$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

How many positive integer solution are there such that for ordered pairs $a,b$ , we get $ab<250$

Is there any general method to solve this type of questions? What if we replaced $250$ with $x$ ?

Like, something, number of ordered pairs of positive integers $a,b$, such that, $$ab<x$$
Can this be solved without brute force method?

Comment: You could consider the [prime factorization](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=prime+factorization+of+250) of $250$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function I don't think the prime factorization of $ x$ helps.

Answer (score 2):

We will count the solutions such that $a<b$, multiply that by $2$ and add the solutions with $a=b$ ( they are $15$), to obtain the final answer.

The number of solutions with $a<b$ is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{15} \lfloor{249}/i \rfloor- i $

This is $248+122+80+58+44+35+28+23+18+14+11+8+6+3+1 = 699$.

So the final answer is $2 \times 699 + 15 = 1413$.

Note: this is sometimes called the hyperbola trick.

Comment: Could you please provide a bit of context on the formula $\sum_i^{250} \lfloor 249/i\rfloor -i$?

Comment: When $a$ is equal to $i$ the value of $b$ has to be among $1, \dots , \lfloor 249/i \rfloor$, but the first $i$ values are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know of any general formula for the floor sum? Like if the constraints are higher, it will be a pretty complicated and time consuming task.

Comment: Hello @Akif_713, I think this question can help you ! https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19562/computational-complexity-of-the-divisor-summatory-function . In particular it appears there is a $\sqrt[3]{n}$ approach in one of the answers. While the accepted answer discusses why a polynomial answer ( in terms of $\log(n)$ ) is not to be available.